# Setting a decimal value on a form doesnt always work - Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Hope someone can help with this. I know how to set a field value on a form and it works in a way. My query is around the fact that it only works if I put this line below into the form load event as a line by itself.

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute('cal_entrynumber').setValue(1.01);`

However, in reality I need to have some conditional checks before I set this value and when I put this line into those conditional checks, then what I notice is that the textbox is blank but if I look at the value in the data entity it does indicate it has the value of 1.01.

`alert("No. in entity:" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('cal_entrynumber').getValue());`

So I wanted to know if anyone can pinpoint me to anything that potentially might be the cause for this ... here is the code in which the line sits (and doesnt work).

```
var queryString = "?$select=cal_EntryNumber&$filter=cal_SafetyProgrammeNo eq '" + spNo + "'&top=1&$orderby=cal_EntryNumber desc";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
    "cal_operation",
    queryString,
    function (results) {
        //alert(results.length);
        if (results.length == 0) {
            //var entry = 1.01;
            //alert("Entry No:" + Number(entry));
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute('cal_entrynumber').setValue(1.01);

        }
        else {
            // Code to go here.                              
        }
    },
    errorHandler,
    function () {
        // OnComplete handler
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").setValue(parseFloat(eval(1.01)));
```

Or this should also work.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").setValue("1.01");
```

References:

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/487202fe-9982-45e1-8133-33b883927c35/haw-to-set-the-precision-of-a-dicimal-field-using-javascrip?forum=crmdevelopment

http://mscrmtutorials.blogspot.com/2015/10/get-or-set-values-of-all-data-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found out why this doesnt work (even though the code is correct) and I'm posting my answer here to help anyone else who might have the same issue.

The Entry Number field gets focus when the form loads and this was emptying the field of its (javascript set) value. I fixed this by putting another textbox field as the first field on the form and now the field is showing the javascript set value (no code changes were required).

I suspect this worked when I put the code into the form load event by itself as it gets run synchronously but when I put the same line of code into retrieveMultipleRecords success callback function, as this runs Asynchronously, it presents this issue. Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.